# NHibernate many to many mapping

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, many-to-many

So I have a situation I'm trying to map with NHibernate. Say we have the following schema:

```
Question
- QuestionID
- QuestionText
- SiteID

Tag
- TagID
- TagName
- SiteID

QuestionTags
- QuestionID
- TagID
```

This would work fine for that:

```
<class name="Question" table="Questions">
      <key column="QuestionID" />
      <property name="QuestionText" not-null="true" />
      <property name="SiteID" not-null="true" />

      <set name="Tags" table="QuestionTags">
        <key column="QuestionID" />
        <many-to-many class="Tag" column="TagID" />
      </set>
</class>

<class name="Tag" table="Tags">
      <key column="TagID" />
      <property name="TagName" not-null="true" />
      <property name="SiteID" not-null="true" />
</class>
```

However, I want to add a SiteID column to QuestionTags, and add SiteID to each of its foreign keys...

```
(QuestionTags.QuestionID, QuestionTags.SiteID) -> (Questions.QuestionID, Questions.SiteID)
(QuestionTags.TagID, QuestionTags.SiteID) -> (Tags.TagID, Tags.SiteID)
```

...so that Questions and Tags with differing SiteIDs cannot be associated. How can I map that situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there an external requirement to have the SiteID column on the QuestionTags table? The Question and Tag already have SiteID and the domain model can enforce that a Tag can't be assigned to a Question with a different SiteID. So from an application perspective, you don't need it.

The join/maping table for a many-to-many relationship only supports two columns. Keep in mind that this table does not represent an entity, but only the relationship between entities. If you add any additional data/columns, then it will need to become an entity in its own right with relationships to the other two entities. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992895/nhibernate-many-to-many-mapping-with-additional-columns-in-the-mapping-table) for an example of an intermediate entity to support another column in the mapping table.